# Android - Load application level data at startup using a LoaderManager

Tags: java, android

I would like to load application level data -singleton- to be available to all activities and services.

I extended the Application object to fetch a model from DB and load it in memory to make accessible to every application component.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

**What I am asking for is:**

1- How to call ***getSupportLoaderManager()*** from the Application context?

2- Is there a way to display a particular fragment -Splash Screen- while the application object is being created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How to call getSupportLoaderManager() from the Application context?* - you don't(you could however use a loader to load the data in the first activity that starts and then put it in the Application class). Loaders are tied to activities and fragments to load the data. 2. No

Comment: @Luksporg I've already did this before and my application crashed because the application data was null. This case happens when you are in activity B -> you receive a call -> for any reason the android system remove the app from memory -> when you return back to Activity B the Application object gets instantiated without calling the first activity and data in application object is null.

Comment: You shouldn't be blindly trying to access the data that you(suppose) have in the Application class. Test for that data being there and if not, get it again.

Comment: @Luksporg What's the better approach if the data is not there? to remove all activities from the stack and start the first activity again or to load the data directly whitin the Application class?

Comment: Get it in the activity where you currently are. You could have a base class from which all your activities extend and in that base class implement the code to get the data. This way all the activities will have the abilities to load/reload data in the application class if not available yet.

Comment: @Luksporg I appreciate your help. I'll try this approach :)